# unable to change button color using css and javascript

Tags: html, css

I would like my button to change color. Currently, when I select it, nothing happens. I used javascript for my button function to change the color.
I have added my javascript and CSS code for more information.
I would like the button color to change to #E68352. I have tried various methods such as using ".active", ":active" and even adding "!important". But unfortunately, nothing works

```css
.booking-container-section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.booking-container-area {
  margin: auto;
  height: 350px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #423F3E;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #E68352 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="try3.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="booking.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="specific-movie-content">
        <div class="specific-movie-img">
        </div>
        <div class="specific-movie-desc">
          <h1 class="specific-movie-title"></h1>
          <p class="specific-movie-para"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="booking-container">
        <div class="booking-container-section">
          <h1 class="booking-seats-font">SEATS</h1>
          <div class="booking-container-area">
            <div class="box">
              <p class="screen-font">SCREEN</p>
            </div>
            <div class="seats-layout">
              <input type="button" id="button1" class="btn" />
              <input type="button" id="button2" class="btn" />
              <input type="button" id="button3" class="btn" />
            </div>
            <p>
               You have selected <span id="display">0</span> seats</p>

            <!--script src="booking.js"></script-->
            <script>
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var count = 0;
var disp = document.getElementById("display");
for (let i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    buttons[i].classList.toggle('active');
    if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
    disp.innerHTML = count;
  })
}
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `:active` is for links mainly but you can use anywhere also it will change color when you click the button and then change back to original

Comment: `:active` is actually applied when you click on a button. If you want the new color to stay, you need to use Javascript.

Comment: i forgot to add this part underneath seat-layout division. 
      <p>
       You have selected <span 
       id="display">0</span> seats
      </p>
 Javascript: var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var count = 0;
var disp = document.getElementById("display");
for (let i = 0, l = buttons.length; i < l; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    buttons[i].classList.toggle('active');
    if (this.classList.contains("active")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
    disp.innerHTML = count;
  })
}

Comment: Please update the question instead of adding code in comments

Comment: I have added my javascript code!

Comment: Please describe the expected result, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Is it "when I click the button, it should change the color permanently (at least until the page is reloaded)"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, to let the button active it need to add button:focus not only :active

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach(function(el) {
 el.addEventListener("click", function() {
   el.classList.toggle("active");
 });
});
```

```css
.booking-container-section{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

.booking-container-area{
    margin: auto;
    height: 350px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #423F3E;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #E68352 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="try3.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "booking.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="specific-movie-content">
                <div class="specific-movie-img">
                </div>
                <div class="specific-movie-desc">
                    <h1 class="specific-movie-title"></h1>
                    <p class="specific-movie-para"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="booking-container-section">
                <h1 class="booking-seats-font">SEATS</h1>
                    <div class="booking-container-area">
                    <div class="box"><p class="screen-font">SCREEN</p></div>
                        <div class="seats-layout">
                        <input type="button" id="button1" class="btn" />
                        <input type="button" id="button2" class="btn" />
                        <input type="button" id="button3" class="btn" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this way when the button looses the focus it's back to black.

Comment: @Azu I know, but he didn't add the javascript, that's why I did on this way :)

Comment: i have added my javascript code!

Comment: @user15423620 I have updated the code check that :)

Comment: i would like to select and deselect multiple buttons while also changing the color of it in the same time. The code does not allow so

Comment: @user15423620 then do the question more clear and not  "I would like my button to change color." but hang on I will change the code again so you can do that

Comment: @user15423620 have a look now :)

Comment: THANK YOU! it work!